# Is there copy-index-assign operation in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, slice, assign, scatter

Is there in [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) one single copy-index-assign operation (to change elements of sub-slice or sub-indexes of an array with copying), doing the same as two last lines of code below?

```
import numpy as np
a, b = np.zeros([4, 6]), np.ones([2, 3])
c = np.copy(a)
c[1:3, 2:5] = b
```

I want to do that in one line:

```
c = np.copy_index_assign(a, np.s_[1:3, 2:5], b)
```

I think this is usually called `scatter` operation, like there's [tf.scatter_nd](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd) in [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/).

Good short name for copy-and-assign is probably `np.replace`.

There are [np.insert](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html), [np.append](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html), [np.delete](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) all of which insert/append/delete elements returning modified copy, but is there same function for assignment (replacemenet of elements) like `np.replace`, that returns copy with replaced elements?

Of cause I can `def` a simple function doing this like in code below, but maybe there is already such built-in operation in standard NumPy?

```
def replace(a, obj, b):
    c = np.copy(a)
    c[obj] = b
    return c
```

Also if there's no built-in operation, can this operation be implemented in one-liner somehow?

Also would be nice if such operation besides assigning to slice supports assigning to a given array of indexes.

Comment: There are functions/methods with names like `copyto`, `put`, `place`, but I can't think of anything that will give both a copy and the full power of index assignment (with broadcasting).

Comment: @hpaulj The reason I was thinking about both copying and assigning is due to the fact that almost all functions/operations in numpy are all immutable meaning that instead of in-place operationing they return a modified copy. Hence same wanted to have for assignment. Immutable operations are nice because they can be chained in one-liner.

Comment: @hpaulj There is also `np.insert` and `np.append` and `np.delete`, but no operation for replacing (assigning) elements. Although replacement can be actually implemented by two operations `np.delete` plus `np.insert`.

Comment: I would not put `insert`, `append` and `delete` in this category.  They are costly functions that return new arrays.  They have to because the result has a different size.  `append` is a just a cover for `concatenate`.